# Telegram Messenger Running Project still met: Unfortunately, Telegram has stopped

Tags: android, apk, telegram

I tried to download source from Telegram Messenger GitHub, using Android Studio, I run the project with the target my Lenovo Mobile ( connected )

In the mobile shows error : Unfortunately, Telegram has stopped

Mind to advise. Many thanks and best regards.

The CatLog mainly seems like this :

```
09-28 11:50:37.263  15071-15071/org.telegram.messenger E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.telegram.messenger, PID: 15071
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.IntroActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: App ID length must be 32 characters.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: App ID length must be 32 characters.
        at net.hockeyapp.android.utils.Util.sanitizeAppIdentifier(Util.java:144)
        at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.initialize(CrashManager.java:347)
        at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.register(CrashManager.java:124)
        at net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager.register(CrashManager.java:112)
        at org.telegram.messenger.AndroidUtilities.checkForCrashes(AndroidUtilities.java:769)
        at org.telegram.ui.IntroActivity.onResume(IntroActivity.java:238)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to obtain and enter the following details in src/Messenger/BuildVars.java to successfully run the app:

1. Telegram App ID and App Hash
2. Google Cloud Messaging App ID: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
3. Hockey API Key

https://rink.hockeyapp.net/
Go to this link and register yourself. Then create a new android app by entering its details and obtain the api key.

The Telegram app will build and run sucessfully once you have entered all of these correctly in the BuildVars.java file.

Comment: This is the right answer. The error message 'App ID length must be 32 characters' is complaining about the Hockey API Key though

Comment: You are right, that is exactly what the error message means. Initially it was confusing as the Telegram ID is just a number and not a 32 character hash.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have not created Teligram project. Kindly follow the link given below and get your APPID
https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id

Post which you should add it to teligram project. Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Greetings from Jakarta, thank you for reply :). I have obtained my API ID and already inputed in BuildVars. Is GCM needed for now ? I have added just APP_ID and APP_HASH.

Comment: public static int APP_ID = 41367;
    public static String APP_HASH = "b887f8aa3e1b0a7e7a67468eadab50b2";
    public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH = "";
    public static String GCM_SENDER_ID = "";

Comment: oops allowed to post codes like that here ? sorry very newbie

Comment: Setup GCM app for that https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Hope that is a solution. Thank you  @vinay-jayaram hufff how to mention lol

Comment: Dear Friend, now it is running well after I fill hockeyapp key... Thank you for all kindness...

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to obtain hockeyapp key?

Comment: what's hockeyapp and why is it required in the telegram project? please consider to explain it. I'm still unable to run the project got from github

Answer (score 0):

as @Abhijay Kumar mentained .
you must do two step , like this :

1 . Telegram App ID and App Hash
you can get telegram app id in :

[get telegram app key](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id)

2 . Hockey API Key
you can get hockey api key in :

[get hockey api key](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/)